# progress-radial, linear-gradient in XSL-FO

Tags: svg, progress-bar, xsl-fo, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

Is it possible to create a radial progress bar in XSL-fo using SVG or something else?

I have a task to generate a pdf document from an XSL that I write in xsl-fo. Our CSS specialist did the coding for it (but cannot help me with the pdf generation and xsl-fo), but not sure how I could recreate it in xsl-fo, so that the pdf document also has the correct progress bar with the achieved percentage.

This is what I should recreate: 
[Radial progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4wyh.png)
Part of his CSS code is:

```
.progress-radial {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #aa94a8;
    background-color: #5d2f5d
}
.progress-radial .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #6c566a
}
.progress-0 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #aa94a8 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(90deg, #5d2f5d 50%, #aa94a8 50%, #aa94a8)
}
.progress-1 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #aa94a8 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(93.6deg, #5d2f5d 50%, #aa94a8 50%, #aa94a8)
}
.progress-2 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #aa94a8 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(97.2deg, #5d2f5d 50%, #aa94a8 50%, #aa94a8)
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Point your browser here https://codepen.io/JMChristensen/pen/Ablch and take a look at code. You can test a few things and see how they "draw" the SVG in code. Then you can adapt that to draw the SVG into the XSL FO based on your input percentage and also modify to your own look and feel.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some inspiration to run with. Given this XML:

```
<charts>
   <chart percent="20"/>
   <chart percent="40"/>
   <chart percent="90"/>
</charts>
```

And using this simple XSL (I have eliminated all the XSL FO page stuff):

```
<xsl:template match="charts">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="chart">
    <fo:block>
        <fo:instream-foreign-object>
            <xsl:call-template name="drawchart">
                <xsl:with-param name="percent" select="@percent"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="r" select="90"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </fo:instream-foreign-object>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="drawchart">
    <xsl:param name="percent"/>
    <xsl:param name="r"/>
    <xsl:variable name="c" select="2*3.1415926*$r"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pct" select="((100-number($percent)) div 100)*number($c)"/>
    <svg id="svg" width="200" height="200" viewport="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle r="{$r}" cx="100" cy="100" fill="none" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1em" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
        <circle id="bar" r="{$r}" cx="100" fill="none"  cy="100" stroke="#FF9F1E;" stroke-width="1em" stroke-dasharray="565.48" style="stroke-dashoffset: {$pct}px;"></circle>
    </svg>
</xsl:template>
```

You get this as output in PDF:

[image]

You can add the text (percent) inside the SVG, change colors, sizes and direction/start for the stroke as you like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helped. I think the equation does not work for me. Even if I specify the percentage, it shows it on 100% (I found a call typo in the yellow color code, but it was not the main problem)

Comment: It did not work for you because my example uses style="" attribute. It was formatted with RenderX. You are likely using FOP which did not support it and you put the stroke-dashoffset as a direct attribute. You should at least upvote the 99% answer I gave you as your answer is almost a copy of mine.

Comment: Kevin, I did upvote your answer the minute I saw it, but the system says that votes by people under 15 reputation are recorded but not publicly shown. Like I said in my answer, I wouldn't have been able to do it without your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AH Formatter, then you can use `linear-gradient()`.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf64/ahf-ext.html#linear-gradient.  Otherwise, you may be able to generate what you want as SVG inside an `fo:instream-foreign-object`.